# how to iterate over consecutive pairs in arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, arraylist

I want to create a loop that iterates through an ArrayList of objects.

```
for (int i = 0,  k=i+1; k < arr.size(); i++) { 
     int tprice;
     tprice=0;
     if (arr.get(i).getID()=arr.get(i+1).getID()) {
        tprice = arr.get(i).getPrice() + arr.get(i+1).getPrice();
     }
     else {
           if (tprice!=0) {
              System.out.println(tprice);
              }
           else {
              System.out.println(arr.get(i).getDuration());
              }
       }
    }
```

I want to compare element `i` to element `i+1` of the ArrayList, without creating a nested for loop as I am not interested in all the permutations. (e.g, `1->2` then `2->3`, not `1->2` then `1->3`)

However, my line of code always causes an error because index `k` at the end of the loop is referencing an out-of-bounds index (or the equivalent for ArrayList).

Say i have three arrays : i=0 compares to i=1, i=1 compares to i=2, i=2 compares to i=3 but throws back an error since it doesn't exist.

Is there any way to overcome this? It seems silly, but I couldn't find anything about it across the forums.

exemple hardcode:

```
         arr.add(new object(444,24))  // 444 is ID, 24 is Price
         arr.add(new object(444,29))  // 444 is ID, 29 is Price
         arr.add(new object(121,33))  // ...
```

wanted outcome :

```
       53
       53
       33
```

side-question : if i am dealing with the same ID, i would ideally wish to print only once. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Just don't iterate to `arr.size()` but stop at `arr.size() - 1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you touch the two consequent elements of the array, you have to stop one element before you read the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size() - 1; i++) {
   // do stuff with arrayList.get(i) and arrayList(i+1)
}
```

Of course, the arrayList must contain at least two elements otherwise the loop will never be entered since the `arrayList.size() - 1` would be equal to `0`.

---

Moreover, you confuse arrays with `ArrayList<T>`.

- `List<T>` of size `list.size()` has methods `list.add(T t)` and `list.get(int index)`.
- An array `int[] array` of size (length) `array.length` access to items with index `array[0]`.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up on the array and arrayList. I assume i didn't make my issue clear enough : I am looking for a way to process the first element of one of my first array and compare it to the second one, the second first element to the third, etc. By reducing the condition to size()-1, i won't get an error but it won't process my last array, as the condition is met before it the loop iterates over it. If i have three arrays, whence the third iteration is reached, it can't process as i+1 is indexing an empty array. I edited the main post to clear out confusion.

Comment: Please, provide the example of these 3 arrays and a sample iteration and the expected result, then the question will be clear.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to check is the `adjacent` elements in the array, just start from the index `1` till the end and compare the adjacent: `current` and `previous`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    if (arr.get(i) > arr.get(i-1)) ....
}
```

Comment: An element with `.size()` method and access via `[]` does not exists.

Comment: @azro Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size-- It's **ArrayList** OP is using ArrayList though it's coded as `arr` here.

Comment: I let you look to some of my answers about Java, do not matter for me about this I have the level ;) I won’t change my argument , a List cannot be accessed via [] only array can ;)

Comment: You are making a confusion. Read Nikolas bottom answer

Comment: @azro You're right, I was wrong about the `accessing` part. Just updated it. Thank you pointing it out.

Comment: I think you need to learn more Java and improve your level before answer kind of question ;) but no matter and of course I was right haha I try to not write shit

Comment: Yeah...you're right. However **learning by trying to answer questions** is kind of a way for me. Sorry for this mistake ( ++ shit answer perhaps :))

Comment: @Hearen that was clever, unfortunately this doesn't allow me to process my very first array. If i have n arrays, i want to print each n of them, but i can only print n-1 without throwing an error.

Comment: @roberhue Your **first** array? Sorry? You'd better elaborate your purpose here. I'm losing your point here.